# Is it useful to retag questions for identified species?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I see that the Identification tag is very popular on GL. My opinion is that retagging with the identified species could help users to avoid posting duplicate questions. For example, if someone wants to identify a rose cultivar, when writing the question a suggestion for already identified roses could appear on the Similar questions list.

However, this retagging would need new tags to be created. The problem is that for some species there would be only one or two identifications, and this rarely used tag would clutter the tag list.

Do you have any idea on how to mark these resolved identification questions with their species name, without overcrowding the site?

EDIT: Or maybe a tag for the genus, not for the species?

Answer (score 2):

Tags might help but as you said it will add a lot of clutter. While it can certainly be helpful to add any related tags to the question once it has been answered I am not sure if this will suffice.

I think a better solution might be to require titles for identification questions to be more detailed. Something like

> "Small green bush with yellow flowers — Identification"

instead of

> "Need help identifying this plant".

Once the planat has been successfully identified the name can be added to the title like

> "Small green bush with yellow flowers **[normal name / *scientific
>   name*]** — Identification".

In any case I think something has to be done in order to keep the identification questions organized (useful for future user) and prevent duplicates.

*I actually came on meta to write a post about how we need to do something about the identification questions that basically all have the same title.*

Comment: I like your idea of writing in the title that the question was solved as [name].